# Unable to add Field in AX Table, Event viewer shows Object name exist

Tags: object, field, dynamics-ax-2009, event-viewer

While adding fields, I am facing issue that I am not able to open my table if there is new field added. it shows error like this:
[image: Error that stops open the table]

Whenever a field is added, it shows an error like this:

[image: Synchronize error]

when I check the event viewer, it shows this error:

[image: Event viewer error]

Full error code :
[image: Full error code]
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `SalesTable` is not properly sync'd. This type of error usually just means you need to compile & sync the entire environment to get things "working" better.

Remove your custom fields, compile the table, right click on the table, and synchronize and verify first you can successfully synchronize the individual table. If you can sync it, then sync your entire data dictionary to ensure **everything** is sync'd up...if one table is off (in this way), it can mean there are other tables as well.

You can choose to try and add fields and see if it works, but I would just start with a full system compile & sync.

**Note:** Your `infolog` screenshots cut off the error message. When asking a question, make sure to include the actual error messages and redact personal information. Your event viewer screenshot is also cut off...same thing.

Comment: Hi Alex, after I sync the entire dictionary I found that there are 3 tables also off. they are salestable, DO line and Do Table. their error in event viewer is pretty much the same, but different in name and fields. Should I remove all recently added field and sync again?

Comment: Your comment isn't clear..."DO line" and "Do Table"?? Sync issues can indicate a bigger problem, especially for `AX09` where you may have mismatched table/field ID's. You need an experienced developer to investigate.

Comment: If I would like to find out the root cause what step should I take?

Comment: @Raynon - The error messages you are seeing generally are the root cause. You need to read what they say, look in SQL and investigate, then take action. I'd guess you restored a backup of your live environment over a dev environment, didn't sync, then started creating objects. Wild guess though.

Answer (score 0):

Identify that the ID in SQL is not match with the Table name at AOT .
[image]

[image]